# CSS Distribute elements on the screen

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using ASP.NET (MVC 4 internet application template). I have the master page and within it I embed another page. This embeded page should have the appearance shown here (Draft): http://snag.gy/OGIut.jpg

This page is three column. First column has a groupbox and into it some radio buttons (options). In the second column there are more groupboxes, as seen in figure above (see link above) and the same for third column. Each groupbox has a title, and before the title a checkbox (this is useful for enable or disable the entire groupbox so user cannot select any options within it). In third column at the end there is a plain button (not 3D), and at the bottom of the page there is a grey section where there is a plain button at the rightmost.

So as I am completely new in web and css programming I am thinking about how to organize all this elements in the view to have the appearance indicated in the picture.

Could anyone help and tell me how to do this? any example? I am very frustrated when working with html and css because I find difficult to place the elements in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider to use frameworks to help to place the element on a grid. The most famous one is of course [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) but there is plenty of these http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html. It makes the web development really faster and easier.

Plus, these kind of frameworks comes with JS & CSS library which can be really helpfull to create modern webpage with sliders, smooth scroling, models windiws etc..

Comment: Thanks for the links. I had a look at and they seem interesting for development complex web applications with rich graphics but due to this web application is very very little I was thinking of not using any type of framework, I do not want to establish any dependences witho other third parties frameworks. I am interesting in do it using css and html combination.